# How to iterate numbers with specific times?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and tried to create text file to print the numbers start from 1 to 1800 but every time each number will be iterated with specific times as follows

```
1 will be iterated to 1799 times 
2 will be iterated to 1798 times 
3 will be iterated to 1797 times
.
.
.
1799 will be iterated 1 times
```

i try to write this code

```
myfile = open("/home/user/Desktop/num.txt", "w")

for i in range(1,1799):
    for j in range(1,1799):
        myfile.writelines(" "+str(i)+'\n')
        myfile.write(" ")
        j=j-1
    

myfile.close()
```

but got wrong iterates .. i think the problem in second for loop i need to make iterates minus one each time after complete its work

Comment: are you sure 1800 won't be printed once and 1799 won't be printed twice?

Comment: 1800 not appeared but 1799 is iterates more than 1000 times

Comment: Could you post an output desired?, or little example?

Comment: You cannot have 1800 '1' and 1 '1799' If you begin with 1800 '1' you must end with 2 '1799' and 1 '1800'

Comment: yes you are right .. i'm conflicting with numbers as i have huge data and countered wrong .. thanks for your answer and help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It is much faster that other way that use double loops:

```
myfile = open("/home/user/Desktop/num.txt", "w")

for i in range(1,1800):
    temp=[(' '+str(i)+'\n') for k in range(i,1800)]
    myfile.writelines(temp)

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Is it really faster? A list comprehension I thought was syntactic sugar for a loop. So I would consider this to be fundamentally using two loops as well, unless there are some crazy list comprehension optimizations I'm not aware of. I suppose I wouldn't be super surprised if there's a speed gain from doing a single writelines call vs multiple ones.

Comment: The dealy is caused due to the write function not the loop themselves. In your solution (which I also tried firstly) we execute 1.6 million write commands, while in my solution we execute only 1800 write commands. This is were the time gain comes from

Comment: If writelines combines everything in RAM and does a single write command then makes sense as opposed to writing each individual line. But following that argument further, we could just collect ALL lines in RAM, join them, and do a single write for even more of a performance gain (time not space).

Comment: I tested it and has not significant difference, probably going from 1.6 million writes to 1800 was huge improvement but going further from 1800 to 1 writes made no difference

Comment: i made the changes in for loop as the logic of iterate times but number " 1 " is still iterated 1800 ! can you please see my edit post

Comment: @user1 Code updated, it should work properly now

Comment: thanks for your time but i implemented it and cursor in text file count line 1800 at the last line of number 1

Comment: @IoaTzimas interesting, thanks for sharing your test results

Comment: @user1 I just tested it and works fine: 1799 times for the '1' down to 1 time for '1799'
I would suggest you delete the 'num.txt' file from your directory, before running my code

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want a file with one number per line with the first 1799 lines being 1's, the next 1798 lines being 2's, ..., down to 1799 being printed once.

```py
N=1799
with open("/home/user/Desktop/num.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        for j in range(N+1-i):
            myfile.write(f'{i}\n')
```

The following might have a performance gain:

```py
with open("/home/user/Desktop/num.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(''.join([f'{i}\n' * (1800-i) for i in range(1,1800)]))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering .. if i need the first number iterates 1799 and the last number which is 1799 iterates once .. i tried to make 2 for loop become 1799 and the second the same number .. but got 1800 times !

Comment: @user1 in python range(a,b) goes from a to b-1 inclusive, which contains (b-a) items. So range(1,10) is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, and is (10-1)=9 items. So if you want 1799 items starting at 1, you would do range(1,1800) because a=1,b=1800 and (b-a)=1799 = number of items. So replace the spots where I have 1801 with 1800.

Comment: @user1 changed answer to reflect 1799

Comment: i'm stuck in 1800 .. every change i made it is still count 1800 times !! .. i tried your edit code and still 1800 for the first number

Comment: i tried N=1799
with `open("/home/user/Desktop/n.txt", "w") as myfile:
    for i in range(1,N):
        for j in range(N-i):
            myfile.write(f'{i}\n')` but still count 1800 for the first number

Comment: @user1 my j loop is range(N+1-i) not range(N-i). For the first number, i=1, so range(N+1-i) is equivalent to range(1799+1-1) = range(1799). This will be a result with 1799 items (which are 0 to 1798, although that doesn't matter). This is 1799 items, not 1800 items. You count 1800? Manually? With some other script? I question the count that says there are 1800 lines with the number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

solution 1:

```
count= 5
i= 0
j = 1
while i != count:
    j = 1
    print("{} will run for {}".format(i+1,(count-i)))
    i+=1
```

solution 2:

```
count= 5
i= 1
i_count= count+1
while i != i_count and count>=0:
    print('{} will run {} times'.format(i, count))
    for k in range(1,count+1):
        print(k)
    count-=1
    i+=1
```